# Can anyone explain the very beginning of The Analysis of Matter to me?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics, physics, aesthetics, bertrand-russell

Can anyone explain the very beginning of The Analysis of Matter to me? What exactly is it that he is saying is an aesthetic choice with respect to physics?

I just opened up [the book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_GqBe7xIqeIC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) and can't get past the first two pages.

Comment: If you don't include the text you don't understand, you rely on other people having the book in question within easy reach.

Comment: it can be found on google books which i will link to, but it's a page and i dunno if i have the energy to write it all out in defeat mode :/

Comment: Links can have any address behind them, so many people are wary of them. Remember, this is a website where people volunteer to answer questions. It is generally a good idea, therefore, to put in at least the amount of effort you would like someone to put into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mathematics, the elegant solution is preferred as a matter of faith.  This is related to Occam's Razor, which prefers succinctness as a guide to choosing a solution amongst those available.

Here, Russell sites Euclidean Geometry can be formulated as a theory using different sets of axioms.  The particular axioms we use have been chosen based on the elegance and economy of the resulting theory of geometry in the plane.